What airplane is this? Seems like a Douglas?
What is this airplane? I flew to Homestead General Aviation airport (X51), and at the ramp (Homestead Executive Jet Center) I saw this aircraft:

I thought this might be a Douglas DC aircraft but I have no idea what it exactly is.

Convair 240 N99380 built as a T-29B for the United States Air Force with s/n 51-5118.

Are you asking about the big white or the small grey airplane?

It looks like a Convair CV-240.
"The Convair CV-240 is an American airliner that Convair manufactured from 1947 to 1954, initially as a possible replacement for the ubiquitous Douglas DC-3. Featuring a more modern design with cabin pressurization, the 240 series made some inroads as a commercial airliner, and had a long development cycle that produced various civil and military variants. Though reduced in numbers by attrition, various forms of the "Convairliners" continue to fly in the 21st century".
